# off screen drawing in android

Tags: android, image, graphics

is there off screen drawing possible in android like a imageContext in objective C. if it is kindly tell me the link or some kind of hint.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) object.  This doesn't have to be on the screen when you draw on it (lines, shapes, bitmaps, etc.).

You'll first want to [create a Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap) to draw on.

Comment: canvas draws on screen images.... anyway how can i get image from canvas. if you know please tell me this because i have read the canvas api but didn't seem any method about getting image from canvas.

Comment: Canvases CAN be used to draw on the screen, but they don't have to.  Create a Bitmap, give it to a canvas, and draw away.  You have a reference to the Bitmap because you created it, you don't need to ask the canvas to get the image back.

Comment: i am totally stuck here canvas is too slow to move a map. now i am thinking about drawing my tiles off screen and get the image from that and give it to imageView to see my map. but cannot find anything which draws images off screen.

Comment: I mean you can always resort to OpenGL to perform complex/highspeed drawing operations but the Canvas object is perfectly capable of drawing several bitmaps (tiles) onto another bitmap.  My advise is to actually try it.  It is capable of drawing "off screen" though...  Just don't assign the Canvas to a UI control.

Comment: There might be some inefficiency in your code besides the fact that you're using a canvas.  Perhaps you could post some if relevant or start a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `FingerPaint` application in `ApiDemos/Graphics`

Comment: nope that is not the solution i need to draw my images offscreen and then get that images as single image and move on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ii is possible to draw off screen by creating a canvas, assign it to a mutable bitmap and doing all drawing with canvas method, like this:

```
Canvas c = new Canvas();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this, R.drawable.mybasebmp); // this is NOT MUTABLE!!
Bitmap bmpm = bmp.copy(bmp.getConfig(), true); // create a MUTABLE copy to draw on it
Bitmap bmpt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this, R.drawable.mytilebmp); // this is my tile
c.setBitmap(bmp);
Rect r = Rect(100,100,149, 149); // scaled to 50x50 pix to draw at position 100,100 in mybasebmp
c.drawBitmap(bmpt, null, r, null); // put a tile at 100,100
r.set(150,170, 150+50-1, 170+50-1); 
c.drawBitmap(bmpt, null,r, null); // put a tile at 150,170

// assign my drawn bitmap to an imageview to show it
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
iv.setImageBitmap(bmpm);
```

We use a canvas to do all the drawing in a mutable BMP and then we put that BMP in a viewable container like an imageview.

Hope it helps someone, I couldn't find any suitable tutorial to do this.

Comment: Create a another canvas with new Canvas(bitmap) is no hardware accelerated, so in the game, it slows down the app, the fps decreases