# How to update canvas draw text instead of redraw canvas

Tags: android, text, android-canvas, draw

I am able to draw a text on canvas on motion view now the problem is that when i draw                   text & go for the next draw on same canvas my draw text is getting disappear i mean screen is getting redraw because of invalidate i want keep my previous draw and make new draw on same canvas how am i going to do that ?

```
@Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint hint = new Paint();
    path = new Path();
    mTextPaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    Log.v("getting mtextpaths", mTextPaths.toString());

    int m;
    if (strgettile != null) {
        for (m = 0; m < strgettile.length(); m++) {
            System.out.println(strgettile.charAt(m));
            char convertst = strgettile.charAt(m);
            characterToString = Character.toString(convertst);

            // canvas.drawText(characterToString, x, y, hint);
            // canvas.drawText(characterToString, m
            // * width + x, m * height + y, foreground); //its working in
            // cross
            // canvas.drawText(characterToString, x, m * height + y,
            // foreground); //its working for vertical
            // canvas.drawText(characterToString, m
            // * width + x, y, foreground); //its working in horizontal
            // setSelectedTile(tile);
            if (getorientation.equalsIgnoreCase("Horizontal")) {
                canvas.drawText(characterToString, m * width + positionX,
                        positionY, foreground); // for motion event
                hint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                hint.setTextSize(45);
                foreground.getTextPath(characterToString, 0,
                        characterToString.length(), positionX * 2 / 3,
                        positionY - 4, path);

            } else {
                canvas.drawText(characterToString, positionX, m * height
                        + positionY, foreground);
                hint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                hint.setTextSize(45);
                foreground.getTextPath(characterToString, 0,
                        characterToString.length(), positionX * 2 / 3,
                        positionY - 4, path);


            }


        }

    }

  public void setSelectedTile(String tile, String strorientations) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("getting string in puzzle view ", tile);
    strgettile = tile;
    getorientation = strorientations;
    mTextPaths.add(path);
    invalidate();


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [off screen drawing in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733298/off-screen-drawing-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

1. Canvas is creating every time whenever you are calling the
   invalidate() method. So I am maintaining all the text and positions
   in arraylist and draw the canvas whenever clicking on the canvas.
2. It is one of the way to solve your problem. A canvas is just a
   bitmap. Whatever you draw on it is permanent. There are ways to
   handle it but again most implementations just redraw the entire
   canvas on every pass.

   Below is code snip:

   ```
   public class PuzzleView extends View {
   private static final String TAG = "Sudoku";
   private float width; // width of one tile
   private float height; // height of one tile
   private int selX; // X index of selection
   private int selY; // Y index of selection
   private final Rect selRect = new Rect();
   private final Game game;
   float positionX = 5;
   float positionY = 15;
   ArrayList<Kirti> data = new ArrayList<Kirti>();
   String strgettile = null;

   Paint foreground = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
   String getorientation;

   String characterToString;
   Path path;
   List<Path> mTextPaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

   public PuzzleView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       this.game = (Game) context;
       setFocusable(true);
       setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
       width = w / 9f;
       height = h / 9f;
       // getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
       Log.d(TAG, "onSizeChanged: width " + width + ", height " + height);
       super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       // super.onDraw(canvas);
       // canvas.save();
       // canvas.restore();
       // Draw the background...
       Paint background = new Paint();
       background.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_background));
       canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);

       // Draw the board...
       // Define colors for the grid lines
       Paint dark = new Paint();
       dark.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_dark));

       Paint hilite = new Paint();
       hilite.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_hilite));

       Paint light = new Paint();
       light.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_light));

       // Draw the minor grid lines
       for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
           canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height, light);
           canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1,
                   hilite);
           canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), light);
           canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight(),
                   hilite);
       }

       // Draw the major grid lines
       for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
           if (i % 3 != 0)
               continue;
           canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height, dark);
           canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1,
                   hilite);
           canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), dark);
           canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight(),
                   hilite);
       }

       Paint hint = new Paint();
       path = new Path();

       int m;
       for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
           String strgettile = data.get(i).getSt();

           if (strgettile != null) {
               for (m = 0; m < strgettile.length(); m++) {
                   System.out.println(strgettile.charAt(m));
                   char convertst = strgettile.charAt(m);
                   characterToString = Character.toString(convertst);

                   if (data.get(i).getorientation
                           .equalsIgnoreCase("Horizontal")) {

                       canvas.drawText(characterToString, m
                               * data.get(i).getWidth()
                               + data.get(i).getXposition(), data.get(i)
                               .getYposition(), foreground); // for motion
                                                             // event

                       hint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                       hint.setTextSize(45);

                   } else {
                       // mTextPaths.add(strgettile);
                       // for (int i = 0; i < mTextPaths.size(); i++) {

                       canvas.drawText(characterToString, data.get(i)
                               .getXposition(), m * data.get(i).getHeight()
                               + data.get(i).getYposition(), foreground);
                       // }

                       hint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                       hint.setTextSize(45);

                   }

               }
               try {
                   if (foreground != null) {
                       foreground.getTextPath(characterToString, 0,
                               characterToString.length(), data.get(i)
                                       .getXposition() * 2 / 3, data.get(i)
                                       .getYposition() - 4, path);
                   }

               } catch (Exception e) {

               }

           }
       }

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
           game.showKeypadOrError(selX, selY);
       foreground.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_foreground));
       foreground.setStyle(Style.FILL);
       foreground.setTextSize(height * 0.75f);
       foreground.setTextScaleX(width / height);
       foreground.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
       FontMetrics fm = foreground.getFontMetrics();
       positionX = (int) event.getX();
       positionY = (int) event.getY() - (fm.ascent + fm.descent) / 2;

       return true;
   }

   public void setSelectedTile(String tile, String strorientations) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Log.v("getting string in puzzle view ", tile);
       if (game.setTileIfValid(selX, selY, tile)) {
           strgettile = tile;
           getorientation = strorientations;
           mTextPaths.add(path);
           data.add(new Kirti(positionX, positionY, strgettile,
                   getorientation, width, height));
           invalidate();
           Log.v("getting mtextpaths", mTextPaths.toString());
       }

   }}
   ```

> The model class is:

```
public class Kirti {
float positionX;
float positionY;
String strgettile;
String getorientation;
float width;
float height;
public Kirti(float positionX, float positionY, String strgettile,
        String getorientation, float width, float height) {
    super();
    this.positionX = positionX;
    this.positionY = positionY;
    this.strgettile = strgettile;
    this.getorientation = getorientation;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
public float getPositionX() {
    return positionX;
}
public void setPositionX(float positionX) {
    this.positionX = positionX;
}
public float getPositionY() {
    return positionY;
}
public void setPositionY(float positionY) {
    this.positionY = positionY;
}
public String getStrgettile() {
    return strgettile;
}
public void setStrgettile(String strgettile) {
    this.strgettile = strgettile;
}
public String getGetorientation() {
    return getorientation;
}
public void setGetorientation(String getorientation) {
    this.getorientation = getorientation;
}
public float getWidth() {
    return width;
}
public void setWidth(float width) {
    this.width = width;
}
public float getHeight() {
    return height;
}
public void setHeight(float height) {
    this.height = height;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is too late anyways
But I hope it's of help to someone else

You should initiatialize your paint and path outside the on draw of the view.

Ondraw is getting called whenever you call the invalidate method so everything is being rerun

Answer (score -3):

I am not going to read that excessively long and horribly formatted code with all the irrelevant event handling included... but in general if you want to save the canvas state between draws, you need to do it explicitly.

Google "android of screen drawing"

[off screen drawing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733298/off-screen-drawing-in-android)

Draw on a bitmap.
Paint that bitmap on the canvas.
Repeat.

Comment: i want to draw a text not an image so how i can use bitmap? correct me if i am wrong@Torben

Comment: sorry for such a long code see i updated my code @Torben